# selenium-side-runner doesn't execute .side file with user profile indicated

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

My aim was to start Chrome with selenium-side-runner, and in profile of my selection.

Opening 'Default' profile

i m using this command for doing but it not opening my Default profile it is opening differt profile without login profile opening. How to open in my default profile.

selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[user-data-dir=/Users/manikanta/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default]" /Users/manikanta/Downloads/qA-NewTest.side